# Why is the max setting for query timeout less than the max queue timeout?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to configure BigQuery projects to leverage Query Queues which are now generally available. Looking at the documentation ([available here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-configuration)), I see:

> `default_query_job_timeout_ms`: The default time after which a query job times out, including the time the job is queued and the time spent running. The timeout period must be between five minutes and six hours.
>
> `default_interactive_query_queue_timeout_ms`: The default amount of time, in milliseconds, that an interactive query is queued. If unset, the default is six hours. The minimum value is 1 millisecond. The maximum value is 48 hours. To turn off interactive query queueing, set the value to -1.
>
> `default_batch_query_queue_timeout_ms`: The default amount of time, in milliseconds, that a batch query is queued. If unset, the default is 24 hours. The minimum value is 1 millisecond. The maximum value is 48 hours. To turn off batch query queueing, set the value to -1.

It seems odd to me that the `default_query_job_timeout_ms` has a max setting of 6 hours which includes queuing time, but the `default_interactive_query_queue_timeout_ms` has a max setting of 48 hours. Wouldn't setting anything more than 6 hours and less than 48 hours just hit the `default_query_job_timeout_ms` anyway?

Am I interpreting this documentation differently than intended?